# how to join two php variables to make one value

Tags: php

Is there any way to join two php value to make one word i have tried this code

PHP

```
for($n = 0; $n <= 2; $n++)
{
    $check+$n = '<"strong">';
}
```

i want it to return some thing like

```
$check0  = '<"strong">';
$check1  = '<"strong">';
$check2  = '<"strong">';
```

joining the values of $n with $check

Comment: Posted an answer showing how to do this with proper arrays.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your code puzzled me greatly at first.  Basically, you want an array, like:

```
$check = array(); // make an empty array
for($n = 0; $n <= 2; $n++)
{
    $check[$n] = '<"strong">'; //put stuff in each index
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Variable variables:

```
<?php
for($n = 0; $n <= 2; $n++)
{
    $varname = 'check' . $n;
    $$varname = '<"strong">';
}
```

Notice the double `$` in line 5.

http://php.net/manual/en/language.variables.variable.php

Comment: Granted that this is possible, why would anyone want to make things that complicated?

Comment: It's in the language for a reason. Sometimes it makes sense.

Answer (score 1):

`$check.$n` will do the trick. You don't use a + like java but a `.`

Comment: No it won't, not on the left side of an assignment like `$check.$n = "hello";` which is what he's trying to do.  You missed a major part of the question.

Comment: Well, you can make it that way by making a new variable. Where the value is `$check.$n`

Comment: Left side, not right. `$x = $check.$n` is fine. `$check.$n = $x` is a major syntax error.

Comment: I know, but with the `$x` you can do what he wanted to do right? Or did i didn't get it?